# Can I set up BTHub-3 to share internet connection when connected to Laptop that uses Wifi via LAN (dhcp not enabled for wifi)

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, lan, internet-sharing

I have BT-Hub3, UTF-45 cable and Laptop that runs on Windows 10. My goal is to share wifi connection from laptop to all other devices (another laptop, ipads and mobile phones) by Connecting BT-Hub3 with Lan cable and feeding the wifi connection from laptop to share to all devices.

Current set up is following: Laptop is connected to local wifi hotspot (that I have no control over) and laptop physically connected via Lan to BTHub-3 into 'BT-infinity' port (that sits next to ADSL), I have shared this connection.
[image]

I expected for this to just work, however the moment I enabled share, I had lost Wifi connection on laptop and when troubleshooting, the error was `dhcp not enabled for wifi`, which then got fixed by Windows 10 troubleshooter and wifi internet started working again on laptop.

**Can I set up BTHub-3 to share internet connection that is provided via LAN  connected to Laptop that has Wifi internet ?**